# Properly set Header X-Auth-Token with Angular 2

Tags: angular, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

New to Angular2 I try to convert an old PHP app to a more modern Angular One.

In my previous version I'm use to call the API and set my X-Auth-Token with the following:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Token:myValidKeyString';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

I can figure out how to solve this `http get`request to external API.

```
getRegionsApi(){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
        headers.append('x-auth-token','myValidKeyString');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http
        .get(this.apiUrl,options)
        .map(res => console.log(res));
    }
```

Of course I import `import { Http, Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`in my service.

Trying replicating several patterns found googling I try:

```
headers.append('Authorization','X-Auth-Token myValidKeyString');
headers.append('x-auth-token','myValidKeyString');
headers.append('x-auth-token','X-Auth-Token myValidKeyString');
headers.append('x-auth-token','X-Auth-Token:myValidKeyString');
```

All of this return a 401(Unauthorized) error.
What did I missed here. Is it my `headers.append' which is wrong, or did I don't use the proper module for that?

Comment: Did you check the request from browser? Does your header request has Authorization keyword? I think `headers.append('x-auth-token','myValidKeyString');` is correct; the keyword is depend on your server.

Comment: Yes I did check. When I make a test using DHC Restlet client in CHrom, I can see the `X-Auth-Token`as a keyword followed by my key In the Request Headers. But in my app I only see `Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-auth-token`. Does it mean I need to set the header to create this keyword?

Comment: Huh, I think the point is `let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });` . It should be `Content-Type`, not `Accept`

Comment: Doing that, the result is `Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type, x-auth-token`but still not the `X-Auth-Token:mykey` expected in request header, but seen using the DHC Restlet plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure why it happen, because I didn't face it before, maybe it come from you server. But in your case, since authorization is in every request, you can consider using `HTTP Interceptor` (the header is same as I said), the tutorial here: https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9#.tka5goka5. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks @ManhLe I'll continue exploring that. I can't control server side. But It's definitly not an Angular issue, as I can't even make that working in classic ajax request. I'll ask community how to understand the Response header in both scenario (testing with DHC and with mis script.